# JSF 2.0 outputText rendered?

Tags: jsf-2

I'm new to JSF and I want to spend a text when an action is executed successfully. But the output text, it is not when the action is executed successfully.

Here is the view (deactivatePerson.xhtml):

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg.personIsDeactivate}" rendered="#{isPersonDeactivate}" />
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{controller.deactivate}" value="#{msg.deactivate}" />
</h:form>
```

Here is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Controller { 
    private boolean isPersonDeactivate = false;

    public String deactivate() {
        isPersonDeactivate = false; // Deactivate process...
        isPersonDeactivate = true;
        return "persondeactivate";
    }

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

Here is the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>persondeactivate</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/deactivatePerson.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Can someone please tell me what I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reference it as a property of the `#{controller}` managed bean. It's unclear what your getter look like, but boolean properties should have a getter prefixed with `is` instead of `get`. The property name itself should preferably not have an `is` prefix. It should rather be a verb statement.

Thus, more so:

```
private boolean personDeactivated;

public boolean isPersonDeactivated() {
    return personDeactivated;
}
```

Then you can reference it as follows:

```
<h:outputText ... rendered="#{controller.personDeactivated}" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, navigation cases are superfluous since the new JSF 2.0 implicit navigation. Just let your action method return `"deactivatePerson"` and it'll go to the proper view without needing a `<navigation-case>`. Make sure that you're reading proper JSF 2.x targeted resources and not JSF 1.x targeted ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked fine. Thanks for the tip. However i have another problem: When I navigate to another page and come back again, the success message is always there. How can I make them invisible? Thanks in advance.